# Is this an appropriate place to ask how to create an autofill script?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to create a script that is able to gather data from online sources using unique identifiers (such as the ChemSpider ID, DrugBank ID, PubChem CID) and use them to fill out a drugbox (similar to that on Wikipedia) and I was wondering if I should ask such a question here or at webapps SE or some other SE site?

Comment: That sounds too broad for the Stack Exchange network generally.

Comment: Any advice on how I might be able to make it sufficiently narrow for SE?

Comment: I don't think you can; do your own research, pick a language and look into the tools available for parsing/scraping web pages.

Comment: I'm a programming noob so how might I find this sort of stuff anyway? I know a PHP script that does something similar to what I want except it does it for a different MediaWiki template and uses different identifiers for it. I would use Google ofc but I don't even know the way to phrase what I'm saying such that it gives Google the right key words to match across the web.

Comment: SE doesn't offer a code-writing or tutorial service. If you already have a related script, put some time into understanding what it does (perhaps start with a PHP tutorial?) and modify it for your needs. If you're not sure what to search for, *"web scraping"* is probably a good start.

Comment: That's right. Usually such questions are closed as *too broad* right away. You should rather find something to deal with, read docs and when you cannot deal with something particular or something is not clear enough either in doc or implementation, so only then ask a question.